# C# Why can't I parse string from networkstream to int for example? TCP Client.Server

Tags: c#, parsing, types, tcp, client-server

I'm getting this:

**Exception thrown: 'System.FormatException' in mscorlib.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll.
The input string is in the wrong format.**

Whenever I try to convert the string I get from

```
string data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, byte_count);
```

to int for example

```
int parsedData = int.Parse(data);
```

and

```
int parsedData = Convert.ToInt32(data);
```

both thow that exception...

What am I missing? HELP :P

Comment: What is the content of the `data` variable you're passing to `int.Parse`? You can easily see it in the debugger, but without it we can't help.

Comment: How to see? to me its a string

Comment: It would appear that whatever value is getting into `data` isn't a valid string representation of an integer.

Comment: thanks you both, @MartinCostello Ok I wil firstl try to make sure its a number like 7 in string format

Comment: add a breakpoint on/after string data. then hover your mouse on string data.

Comment: In the debugger, you can hover your mouse over the `data` variable, or type it into the Watch window, or look at the Locals window

Comment: thanks thanks thanks very much @everyone, turns out as gabriel suggested it simply wasnt convertable to int since it was always a string like a: 7 instead of 7, as defined on the client... thanks=)